# How C++ relocate external symbols address

Tags: c++, c, linker, ld

I met a linking detail question about C/C++.

I've already known that external symbols will relocate at linking phase, but my question is:

how C++ relocate those symbols? By `basic address + offset` way, or just `absolute address`?

More issue in real world:

> I want to build a program A, which has a dependency on static library B.
>
> Meanwhile library B has a dependency on static library C.

When I build static B, library C (version 0.2) imported (weak symbol).
but when I build program A, I misused wrong version library C(version 0.1).

bcuz the symbol names has not changed, no compiling error occurred, but runtime issue
happens: BAD_ACCESS on invalid memory address.

What confused me is, the way linker relocate external symbols. It shouldn't crash when linker relocate every symbol on absolute address, right?

When I misused different version C, there is only one copy of static library C, program A and static B will relocate symbols with version 0.1 C, right?

So the real reason of this crash, I guess, is linker used `basic+offset` way to relocate symbols.

I haven't googled any useful results. Deeply appreciated for anyone who gives help.

Comment: So the problem is that you've compiled code expecting to call C_v0.2. It sets up its arguments and any structures for C_v0.2. Then control is actually transferred to C_v0.1, which expected something different, and crashes. Why would this have anything to do with the symbol relocations?

Comment: yep, just don't understand why, cuz all the C symbols is weak. It should be relocate to same address.

Comment: I'm saying that the address isn't the problem. The behaviour of the code at the address is the problem.